# How can I log every command for which an Ansible playbook uses elevated permissions?

Tags: ansible, logging, audit

I have an Ansible playbook that runs against a Linux target host and uses `become` to gain elevated permissions for those actions that require it.

For auditing purposes, I need a list of all the *Unix commands* that are executed using those elevated rights.

I.e., suppose the playbook uses the `yum` module to install a package:

```
- name: Example
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Provide current Apache
      yum:
        name: httpd
        state: latest
```

I need to see that the `/usr/bin/dnf` binary is called with root permissions.

How can I configure the various logging systems involved to provide that information?

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement auditing in your system, [Configure Linux system auditing with auditd](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-linux-auditing-auditd).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting verbosity level inside Ansible could provide that information.
You could either pass it as an argument '**-vv or -v**' or setting it in the ansible.cfg => **verbosity = 2**

Comment: While this answer is factually correct, I would love to see more context provided as for example done in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18807711/19238131).